# -fopenmp is not recognized by the GCC Compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, minix

I want to use `-fopenmp` in MINX 3, and when I write down the command:
`gcc -fopenmp test.c -o test.out`  it shows me this error:

**cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fopenmp"**

the GCC version of Minix 3 that i am using is GCC 4.1.1. I have to use an old version of Minix, and this is the only version of GCC that it has.

Can the problem be that the version of GCC doesn't have `-fopenmp`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to [GCC's webpage](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp), you will find that the first version of the compiler supporting OpenMP was GCC 4.2, with OpenMP 2.5.

OpenMP 3.0 (with tasking support) was added in GCC 4.4.
OpenMP 4.0 (with dependent tasks) was added in GCC 4.9.